# How come NSRect and CGRect are incompatible types?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Ok , I'm consfused about an error :

> error: incompatible type for argument
>   1 of 'initWithFrame:'

This is what causes it:

```
operationLabel = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height / 2 - (40 * 3), self.frame.size.width, 100)];
```

The definition is:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect;
```

So the first argument is NSRect, lets check it :

```
typedef CGRect NSRect;
```

How can it cause an error? **They are same types named differently!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSRect` is the same type as `CGRect` if building for iOS, for a 64-bit Mac architecture, or a 32-bit Mac architecture with the macro `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` is defined as 1 at the command line or in a prefix header.

Or, to quote NSGeometry.h:

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
```

Answer (score 11):

In addition to zoul's answer I thought I'd mention the two helper functions (macros?) by Apple (starting with 10.5):

```
NSRect NSRectFromCGRect(CGRect cgrect)
CGRect NSRectToCGRect(NSRect nsrect)
```

Answer (score 3):

Where did you get the typedef definition of `NSRect`? According to the docs `NSRect` is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct _NSRect {
      NSPoint origin;
      NSSize size;
} NSRect;
```

In other words, it’s a structure that looks just like `CGRect` (but not a plain `typedef`). There’s already something written about [conversions between CGRect and NSRect](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2007/03/15/rect_conversion/).